# x11vnc display cursor and cursor motion

Tags: x11, vnc, xvfb, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

Well, that question already been asked, however my environment is slightly different. I've robot that moves mouse inside `x11vnc` session. I'd like that cursor motion to be properly displayed with `vncviewer` (`tigervnc-1.4.2-r2`). Seems nothing works.

What I've tried:

`x11vnc -nocursor && vncviewer LocalCursor=0 DotWhenNoCursor=1`

`x11vnc -cursor arrow && vncviewer LocalCursor=0 DotWhenNoCursor=0`

`x11vnc -cursor X && vncviewer LocalCursor=0 DotWhenNoCursor=0`

`x11vnc -cursor some && vncviewer LocalCursor=0 DotWhenNoCursor=0`

`x11vnc -cursor most && vncviewer LocalCursor=0 DotWhenNoCursor=0`

Also plaid some with LocalCursor=1 (although think since I need to see remote cursor that's wrong idea).

Is that possible (not sure I properly understand `vnc` approach for cursor display).

Comment: Same question on different sites: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176127) [2](https://superuser.com/q/811058) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34282363) [4](https://serverfault.com/q/454093)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found solution. Just enabled `-multiptr` option for `x11vnc`.
Got that option working out of the box on `x11vnc-0.9.14-r2` Gentoo Linux version of x11vnc. However, it could be necessary to install additional `x11vnc-multiptr` module.

Answer (score 4):

on ubuntu:

```
git clone git@github.com:LibVNC/x11vnc.git
cd x11vnc
sudo apt-get install libvncserver-dev
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install

xset r rate 200 30    
x11vnc -repeat -multiptr
```

Comment: But, it's anoying, sometimes, the "-multiptr" parameter cause the error ""ERROR creating XInput2 MD""